# Reading a basic file through pd.read_csv

Tags: pandas

I'm starting to go through Ageron's Hands on Machine Learning Book.
I came across a dataset on his github that I'm not able to open properly by myself and would appreciate assistance.
Here's the link of the dataset:
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv

Here's what I tried

```
pd.read_csv("https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv")
```

That clearly didn't work. Then I went through the notebook and basically replicated what he had

and tried to read the dataset as follows:

```
pd.read_csv("https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands=',',delimiter='\t',
                         encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a")
```

I'm still getting tokenizing data errors. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The link you are using points to the github html page that contains the data preview instead of the actual underlying data. To solve the issue make sure to use the github raw link which can be retrieved by clicking the 'Raw' button:

```
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands=',', delimiter='\t', encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a", index_col="Country")
gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015": "GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
gdp_per_capita
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. append `?raw=true` to the URL of the webpage you gave:

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv?raw=true", thousands=',', delimiter='\t', encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a", index_col="Country")
   ```
2. use the full `raw` URL by clicking on "Raw" in the top right of CSV contents:

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands=',', delimiter='\t', encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a", index_col="Country")
   ```

---

If you plan on using many examples in that repository to go with the book, I would suggest instead [cloning the entire repository](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2#want-to-install-this-project-on-your-own-machine).

In a terminal, run the following:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2.git
$ cd handson-ml2
```

You now have the files locally, and can simply use:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv", thousands=',', delimiter='\t',
   ...:                              encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a", index_col="Country")
   ...:
   ...: gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015": "GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)

In [3]: gdp_per_capita.head()
Out[3]:
                                                    Subject Descriptor         Units  Scale                      Country/Series-specific Notes  GDP per capita  Estimates Start After
Country
Afghanistan          Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  U.S. dollars  Units  See notes for:  Gross domestic product, curren...         599.994                 2013.0
Albania              Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  U.S. dollars  Units  See notes for:  Gross domestic product, curren...        3995.383                 2010.0
Algeria              Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  U.S. dollars  Units  See notes for:  Gross domestic product, curren...        4318.135                 2014.0
Angola               Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  U.S. dollars  Units  See notes for:  Gross domestic product, curren...        4100.315                 2014.0
Antigua and Barbuda  Gross domestic product per capita, current prices  U.S. dollars  Units  See notes for:  Gross domestic product, curren...       14414.302                 2011.0
```

*(based on the associated notebook)*